# where can i find sample free data set from super market purchase history with customer id?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, research

I tired with many open sources like https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.html but i couldn't able to find any grocery supermarket data.I am looking for Like purchase history stored in Loyalty card. i am looking for data set with item id,
item name,quantity,price, purchase date , customer id or loyalty id.